# How to share dependencies between different android build variations?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an Android Library project (RealCoolLib). Users of RealCoolLib sometimes want the dependencies packaged in the aar and sometimes they want to use it in the normal gradle way. My build gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode 1
        versionName 1.0.0
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'client-proguard.txt'
        }
        releaseNoPro {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'client-proguard.txt'
        }
        releaseWithJars {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'client-proguard.txt'
        }
        releaseWithJarsNoPro {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'client-proguard.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.googlelib.everyone.needs.this:1.0.0'

        debugCompile 'com.tools.debugversion:0.0.5'
        debugCompile 'org.awesome.stuff.debug:2.0.0'
        debugCompile 'com.another.tool.needed:3.0.0'        

        releaseCompile 'com.tools.releaseversion:1.0.0'
        releaseCompile 'org.awesome.stuff:2.0.0'
        releaseCompile 'com.another.tool.needed:3.0.0'

        releaseNoProCompile 'com.tools.releaseversion:1.0.0'
        releaseNoProCompile 'org.awesome.stuff:2.0.0'
        releaseNoProCompile 'com.another.tool.needed:3.0.0'

        releaseWithJarsProvided file('stuff/com_tools_releaseversion.jar') 
        releaseWithJarsCompile file('stuff/org_awesome_stuff.jar')
        releaseWithJarsCompile file('stuff/com_another_tool_needed.jar')

        releaseWithJarsNoProProvided file('stuff/com_tools_releaseversion.jar') 
        releaseWithJarsNoProCompile file('stuff/org_awesome_stuff.jar')
        releaseWithJarsNoProCompile file('stuff/com_another_tool_needed.jar')
}
```

This results in a lot of repeated dependencies declarations. Is there a way to create a single "unit" that holds on to the list of jar 
dependencies and another with the normal notation? Basically I'm looking for some way to reduce the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
configurations {
    baseConfiguration
    configurationA {
        extendsFrom(baseConfiguration)
    }
    configurationB {
        extendsFrom(baseConfiguration)
    }
}

dependencies {
    baseConfiguration('junit:junit:4.12')
}
```

And then when running `./gradlew dependencies` you can see that `configurationA` and `configurationB` contain same dependencies as `baseConfiguration`:

```
baseConfiguration
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

configurationA
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

configurationB
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

Docs: [extendsFrom](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom)

Comment: I'll give that a shot.

Comment: So tried that, but it seems that since android does something special with it's flavors and variants, I was only able to make one grouping.